# Typescript Use Derived Class as Return Type of Method

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class in typescript which has a method to supply a callback for later use. The return type of the method is the class, so that I can use fluent style coding. I am trying to extend the class but am unsure how to get the method to return the derived class type:

```js
export abstract class Wizard {
   ...

   public onPageChanging(handler: PageChangingHandler): Wizard { // Returns Wizard (but I would like this to be the derived class instead)
       this.onPageChangingHandler = handler;
       return this;
   }

   public onPageChanged(handler: PageChangedHandler): Wizard { // Returns Wizard (but I would like this to be the derived class instead)
       this.onPageChangedHandler = handler;
       return this;
   }
   ...
}

export class StepWizard extends Wizard {
   ...
}
```

Calling code:

```js
export class Foo {

    private wizard: StepWizard;

    ...
    wireUpWizard() {
        this.wizard = new StepWizard({ 
             elem: HTMLElement,
        }).onPageChanging(pc => {
          // Handle Page Changing
        }).onPageChanged(pc => {
          // Handler Page Changed
        });

        // ISSUE: Can't use fluent chaining, as onPageChanging/onPageChanged returns Wizard instead of StepWizard
    }

    ...

}
```

I know I need to use Generics in some fashion to return a Generic type from onPageChanging and onPageChanged, but I have not been able to do it so far.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be looking for the [polymorphic this type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).

```js
export abstract class Wizard {
   ...

   public onPageChanging(handler: PageChangingHandler): this { // <-- here
       this.onPageChangingHandler = handler;
       return this;
   }

   public onPageChanged(handler: PageChangedHandler): this { // <-- here
       this.onPageChangedHandler = handler;
       return this;
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I expected it to be much more complex than this. Many Thanks